# Regex expression doesn't work in ascending order.

Tags: regex

This may be an easy question, but I can't figure it out. 
When I test the following string TEST_NO against 
`\b(?>TEST|TEST_NO)\b` it doesn't match. When I test it against `\b(?>TEST_NO|TEST)\b` it works as expected. Can someone explain why?

Comment: An underscore is considered a word boundary in `\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you intended to use a non-capturing group:

```
\b(?:TEST|TEST_NO)\b
```

---

You're using an **[atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)**. And [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) prevent backtracking.

> An atomic group is a group that, when the regex engine exits from it, automatically throws away all backtracking positions remembered by any tokens inside the group.

This is how it goes:

```
The subpattern               Text

\b(?>TEST|TEST_NO)\b         TEST_NO
^^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^
```

And then it tries to match:

```
The subpattern               Text

\b(?>TEST|TEST_NO)\b         TEST_NO
                  ^^             ^
```

And it fails, so it tries to backtrack, but the atomic group prevents it.

---

You can also see a step-by-step debug in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bC5bX8/1) (click on regex debugger).

[image: regex101 debug]

Answer (score 3):

This regex:

```
\b(?>TEST|TEST_NO)\b
```

will fail to match `TEST_NO` due to use of [**Atomic Group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html).

An atomic group automatically throws away all backtracking positions remembered by any tokens inside the group, when the regex engine exits from it.

Since this regex matches `\bTEST` first it will exit from the atomic group after this point.